# Collectionview item size and amount

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm in tad of a dilemma with an application here. 
Id like a `CollectionView` to be filled with modules and icons, positioned in the center of the display. I'm able to center the `CollectionView` using the AutoLayout helpers, but i cant seem to figure out how to size the items correctly.

Currently, there are 4 items in a row, where as i would like to only have two, ( 50% width ) items in a row.

I figured the `itemSize` attribute, and the corresponding `CGsize method`, but that is only static pixels ( 120, 300 ) And therefor not representative for what i would like both on large and small devices.

Are there any way to make the items lock at:
2 per. row.
50% width + gutter

Thanks in advance!

Jonas

Comment: Have you tried to switch those static values with computed ones like colectionView.bounds.width / 2?

Comment: Sadly with no luck. ModuleListView.bounds.width simply returns 100, which is way less that it actually is :/

Comment: I think you need to set interItemSpacing and section inset as well.

Comment: Hi @user2894531, thanks for your comment. Can you explain that a little more detailed, please?

Comment: You want to fix the space from left side of the collection view and 1st item? Or arbitrary is ok?

Comment: And where are you trying to access ModuleListView.bounds.width?

Comment: I would like there to be simply two items on one row, and then onto the next row with two items and so forth. So each item should fill roughly half of the collectionview. I'm accessing the bounds.width in my viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Dont do in viewDidLoad do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69877/discussion-between-user2894531-and-jonas-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, which has datasource methods like

```
sizeForItemAtIndexPath
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex
```

return custom values to layout collectionview's cells as you want.

Use `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize` to get proper content size. But it will be valid only after collection view completes its layout, so you can just use collectionView's frame instead.